# Side by side images are not working in r markdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am trying to place side by side images in `r markdown` beamer using the code below.

````
```{r, out.width='.49\\linewidth', fig.cap='caption', fig.show='hold', fig.align='default'}
  
knitr::include_graphics(c('figures/yield.png', 'figures/boxplot_yield.png'))
````

However, the images somehow were vertically stacked, instead of horizontally. Please see the resulted plot below. Any ideas??

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When I ran your code with my own pictures, they rendered side by side, you may need to make the pictures a smaller resolution and then your code should do what you want

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I suspect it's not because of the resolution. The problem could be I am using a latex template as an `R markdown` beamer, and some settings in the latex template might be causing the problem....However, I have no idea how to fix it.

Comment: Problem solved by commenting off several code lins in the latex template. Case closed